# Change partition without affecting LUKS encryption

Tags: debian, lvm, luks, zfs

I want to change one of my partitions from `ext4` to something else (`xfs` or `openzfs`), the partition is `sdc5_crypt` and is mounted at startup. My intuition says that I can format it with something like `zpool create sdc_pool sdc5_crypt` without any impact into the LUKS encryption, so that it will still be mounted normally as it is done now, but the `/dev/mapper/sdc5_crypt` partition will now be `zfs` instead of `ext4`

this is my configuration right now:

```
>lsblk
...
sdc              8:32   0  1.9T  0 disk
├─sdc1           8:33   0    1K  0 part
└─sdc5           8:37   0  1.9T  0 part
  └─sdc5_crypt 254:2    0  1.9T  0 crypt /mnt/ssd-3

>mount | grep sdc
/dev/mapper/sdc5_crypt on /mnt/ssd-3 type ext4 (rw,relatime,discard)
```

Am I correct in assuming that the above approach will partition/reformat the `sdc5_crypt` partition without messing up LUKS headers (which are backed up in any case) or something else? Is it safe to do it like this? If not, what would be the suggested way to change the mounted `ext4` partition to be used in a `zfs` pool?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any operations on `sdc5_crypt` will not harm your LUKS configuration. You can treat it like a normal drive. So yes, you should be able to use that command to reformat your partition.